# Hex to lat lon radians conversion

Tags: hex, latitude-longitude, data-conversion, radians

I need to convert a Hex value to latitude/longitude. I didn't succeed in what I tried..
I have for example the Hex value : 0x3F0EFA35 and I know it is E3200000 - East 32 degrees 0 minutes, 0 miliseconds, 
the Hex value represents radians values from -PI to PI.
Anyone knows how to do this conversion?
Thanks!

Comment: What does `E3200000` mean?

Comment: I edited the question to include what it is